# Sending GET request to REST API with custom header

Tags: php, rest, api, get, request

I am trying to send a GET request to a REST API with a custom header, and I've followed tutorials and looked on here, but nothing I tried has worked. Am I missing something from this code?

```
<?php


$curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://manager.gimbal.com/api/beacons/");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $headers = array(
      'Content-type: application/json',
      'authorization: Token token={token}',
  );

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  print($result);

?>
```

I have the correct token, it worked when I used a REST client.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code here, `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` does accept an array (I think that's all it accepts tbh).

Comment: Probably entirely pointless as it should be taken care of on the API, the docs do show `AUTHORIZATION` as capitalized not lowercase as you have here, beyond that no idea.

Comment: capitalised AUTHORIZATION, still nothing. No clue.